# Pandas dataframe 3d visualization with different colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Imagine a dataframe like this:

```
i   X     Y     Z     label  
1   23    45    23    0
2   56    67    24    0
3   34    87    25    0
4   43    78    26    0
5   45    45    37    1
6   34    98    38    1
7   23    45    39    1
8   34    76    40    1
9   54    87    41    1
```

I know how to visualize x,y,z using matplot, but the problem is I want to set the color of each data using the label column, for example all 0 labeled rows should be in green and 1 labeled rows should be orange.
I'm pretty new to python and it would be grate if give an example implementation.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with set color for each `label` and plot `scatter` like below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

np.random.seed(365)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': np.random.rand(200),
    'Y': np.random.rand(200),
    'Z': np.random.rand(200),
    'label' : np.hstack((np.zeros(100),np.ones(100)))})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')

colors = {0 : 'orange', 1:'g'}
for l in df['label'].unique():
    ax.scatter(xs = df.loc[df.label == l, 'X'], 
               ys = df.loc[df.label == l, 'Y'],
               zs = df.loc[df.label == l, 'Z'], 
               color = colors[l])

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]